# Upgraded ver. 15.2.0-rc7 multi..can't see sequence routs as before

Tags: orbot, android

Hi by mistake I clicked new version instead of upgrading & proxy everything. 
Since then cant change to

1. English in language section & there is no "save mode"
2. Can't see or  follow the sequence lines of addresses over the globe as before.. that verified conection disconnection etc.. 
   How do I retrieve the old view

What I mean is that I can't see all the circuit relay addresses & Orbot address info sequences information. The whole skin & appearance has changed How can I correct this.. It has given peace to know exactly minute to minute status.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [FDroid](https://fdroid.org/) and install the [Orbot](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.torproject.android) version available there or you can enable the Guardian Project repository (which is preconfigured in newer versions of FDroid) through the Repositories menu and install the latest stable release from there.

It's worth noting that viewing just one circuit that Tor is using at the time is of little real security value, since Tor will frequently use multiple circuits simultaneously, and you are only seeing one. Either you trust the app and trust the circuits are being built faithfully *or* you don't and it might lie to you about the circuits anyway. The circuit view provides a false sense of security, and is likely misleading you about what you should be concerned about with regards to anonymity and security.